# exit fullscreen embeded youtube in webview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am using embeded youtube in my webview for making a iPhone app. But I have couple of issues. First is, When I start playing video, it automatically goes to full screen. I want it to remain on the same frame while playing. Another issue is, I want it to run automatically. I mean I dont want to manually click run, I want, as soon as the app gets loaded, it should RUN AUTOMATICALLY without manually running, plus it should not run on FULLSCREEN.

Thanks

Akansha

Answer (score 0):

I think you are loading embeded html string for youtube but it's not going to play automatically.

for that you need to put logic like bellow code

```
- (UIButton *)findButtonInView:(UIView *)view
{
UIButton *button = nil;

if ([view isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
    return (UIButton *)view;
}

if (view.subviews && [view.subviews count] > 0) {
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        button = [self findButtonInView:subview];
        if (button) return button;
    }
}

return button;
}


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView
{
self.playButton = [self findButtonInView:theWebView];
[self.playButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

This will play video automatically as loading finished...

Comment: And can you please tell what can i Do to play it in non-fullscreen mode.

Comment: you can't play it in non-fullscreen mode or you can't add it in any viewconroller too, embeded url opens video in default player so you don't have much more access to system controllers.